# How to print output in java

Tags: java, math, printing, double

I have this simple problem I'm trying to do. I'm trying to write a program that doubles these five numbers. Then I want to compute the average of these numbers and print them out. The code runs with no errors, but it will not print my answer for some reason. How can I get it to print the output of the problem or simply print something? I am using Netbeans.

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package marina;

/**
 *
 * @author bax
 */
public class Precedence {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    double grade1 = 100;
    double grade2 = 75;
    double grade3 = 88;
    double grade4 = 65;
    double grade5 = 99;
    int x = (int) (grade1+grade2+grade3+grade4+grade5/5.0);

    System.out.println(x);   

    }
}
```

Output:

```
run:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: What exactly is not working? Do you get an exception? Or not the result you expected?

Comment: how are you running your program

Comment: How do you run your program? From a command-line? From an IDE such as Eclipse?

Comment: i can print the result sucessfuly with your codes. How do you run your program?

Comment: if you using eclipse: try to press Ctrl + F11

Comment: I just ran your program and got output as 85. What is the  problem you are facing?

Comment: I am using Netbeans and the output reads: "run:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)"  It does not show me a number of any sort.

Comment: Where do you run the program from - an IDE or from command line?

Comment: I tried Rebuild. And I am using the IDE Netbeans. It will only output what I updated in my question. "run: BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)" It does not show the answer.

Comment: Make sure you have your file open and press `Shift + F6`. Notice that if you press just `F6` then the main project will be run, not necessarily this project. Also, make sure you hit the `Clean and build` option, to clean up cache and so on.

Comment: @MC Emperor: Thank you! That did the trick. What does Shift + F6 do?

Comment: @Lulu: It runs the *current file*. Since this is the solution, I have posted the above comment as answer. Please mark that as correct answer, so the SO community knows that this question is solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Like I said in the comments:)

Make sure you have your file open and press `Shift + F6`, which runs the *current file*. Notice that if you press just `F6` then the *main project* will be run, not necessarily this project. Also, make sure you hit the Clean and build option, to clean up cache and so on.

Answer (score 1):

group your additions in brackets`(elm1+elm2)/5` and then divide it by 5

```
    int x = (int) ((grade1+grade2+grade3+grade4+grade5)/5);
System.out.println(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

`System.out.println()` will print to the console, so make sure you run it there.

Further, you are not calculating an average. Division has higher precedence than addition. Rewrite like:

```
int x = (int) ((grade1+grade2+grade3+grade4+grade5)/5.0);
```

Comment: Thank you for correcting my calculations. But it still will only give the output I updated in my question.

Comment: `System.out.println()` will print to the standard output, which usually is a console in a terminal, but can be a file or the standard input of another process for example.

Comment: Open the output window, not the build window.

Answer (score 0):

It should print the result but you have also a mistake with the calculation.
You only divide grade5 through 5.0.

This is what you want to do I think:

```
int x = (int) ((grade1+grade2+grade3+grade4+grade5) / 5.0);
```

Try also:

```
System.out.println("Result: " + x);
```

Comment: Thank you, that is how I wanted to calculate it. However, it still will not print my answer. Only the output I updated in my question.

Comment: How do you run your program? If possible, make a screencap

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Eclipse or another IDE to run your program, there should be a "console" window somewhere in the IDE, that will display the console output.

To run your program without an IDE, run the following in a console (cmd on windows, terminal/bash on linux, ...):

```
javac MyFile.java
java MyFile
```

If that doesn't work, you will have to add the JDK binaries to your PATH.

Answer (score 0):

```
int x = (int) (grade1+grade2+grade3+grade4+grade5/5.0);
```

(1+1+1+1+5/5)=5

(1+1+1+2+5)/5 = 2